# Remove first a from $HOME/a/a/b/c

Tags: unix, directory, command, rm, rmdir

I was reading a book on UNIX when I came across this question.
You have a directory structure

```
    $HOME/a/a/b/c
```

where the first **a** is empty.
How do you remove it and move the lower directories up?
I have looked on the man pages of the commands **rmdir** and **rm** but could find nothing.
Please help me.

Comment: Move the second `a` to a temporary location...

Comment: I would use something like mv $HOME/a/a $HOME/a

Comment: If `$HOME/a/a/b/c` exists, then the first `a` is not empty. It contains at least the subdirectory `a`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move subdirectory before remove parent directory. So..

```
mv $HOME/a/a $HOME
rmdir $HOME/a
```

But, this does not work because name `a` collide.

Rename the parent directory to avoid name collision.

```
mv $HOME/a $HOME/temp_a
mv $HOME/temp_a/a $HOME
rmdir $HOME/temp_a
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot move a/a into a, you could instead rename a.

```
mv a a_
mv a_/a .
rmdir a_
```